# Switch SWT progressbar to indeterminate (replacing the widget)

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, progress-bar

It seems impossible to switch the state of a single SWT progressbar widget from determinate to indeterminate (SWT.INDETERMINATE) and back. 
I want to do so based on user interaction, which may be frequently, so disposing and recreating might not be the best idea.

The solution I tried is to hide the determinate bar and show the indeterminate bar and force a re-layout of the parent composite.

By doing this however, the bar will not reappear on the same position, indicating that a hidden element takes up its space. Is it possible to do an in-place replacement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [here](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t95703.html#92150164). Using StackLayout and two ProgressBar instances. Alternatively, use a JProgessBar with `#setIndeterminate(boolean)`

Comment: This link is now dead. Answer no longer useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply wrap the `ProgressBar` in a `Composite`, then `dispose()` it when you want to change it and create a new `ProgressBar` with the style you want:

```
private static ProgressBar  bar;
private static boolean indeterminate = false;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = Display.getDefault();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH).setText("Above");

    final Composite barParent = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    barParent.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    barParent.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    bar = new ProgressBar(barParent, SWT.SMOOTH);
    bar.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    bar.setMaximum(10);
    bar.setSelection(5);

    new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH).setText("Below");

    final Runnable timer = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            if (bar.isDisposed())
                return;

            indeterminate = !indeterminate;

            bar.dispose();
            bar = new ProgressBar(barParent, indeterminate ? SWT.INDETERMINATE : SWT.SMOOTH);
            bar.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
            bar.setMaximum(10);
            bar.setSelection(5);
            barParent.layout();

            display.timerExec(2000, this);
        }
    };
    display.timerExec(2000, timer);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Indeterminate:

[image]

Smooth:

[image]